# Cholesky decomposition of a Kronecker product

Tags: kronecker-product, cholesky-decomposition

Assume that the $n\times n$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$ has the Cholesky decomposition of the form $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}^H$. Now, suppose the matrix $\mathbf{B}$ is the result of a Kronecker product as $\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{I}\otimes\mathbf{I}\otimes\mathbf{A}$ where $\mathbf{I}$ is $2\times 2$ identity matrix. Can we find the Cholesky decomposition of $\mathbf{B}$ in terms of $\mathbf{L}$?

Comment: Isn’t $B$ just block diagonal with four copies of $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is
$$
I \otimes I \otimes A = (I \otimes I \otimes L)(I \otimes I \otimes L)^H.
$$

Comment: The answer is correct. However, for a better answer you should add that you used following two properties:  $AC\otimes BD=(A\otimes B)(C\otimes D)$ and $A\otimes(B\otimes C)=(A\otimes B)\otimes C$.

Comment: Moreover is would prefer to write it $I \otimes I \otimes A = (I \otimes I \otimes L)(I \otimes I \otimes L^H).$ I am not quite sure about the conjugate transpose outside the bracket.